# How to get multiple a lines of text after specific string in the line c#

Tags: c#, .net, steam

this code works but only finds one text even tho there is two texts in file,but sometimes there can be more than two.

```csharp
            var d = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            var t = d.Where(g => g.Contains(cotainstring));
            string[] splited;
            foreach (var item in t)
            {
                splited = item.Split(new string[] { cotainstring}, StringSplitOptions.None);
                return splited[1];
            }
            return null;
```

this is an example file for reading purposes.

```json
    "?????????????"
    {
        "AccountName"       "dummy1"
        "PersonaName"       "imdummy1"
        "RememberPassword"      "1"
        "MostRecent"        "0"
        "Timestamp"     "boring"
        "WantsOfflineMode"      "0"
        "SkipOfflineModeWarning"        "0"
    }
```

and

```json
    "?????????????"
    {
        "AccountName"       "dummy2"
        "PersonaName"       "imdummy2"
        "RememberPassword"      "1"
        "MostRecent"        "0"
        "Timestamp"     "boring"
        "WantsOfflineMode"      "0"
        "SkipOfflineModeWarning"        "0"
    }
```

but my code only gets dummy1, not dummy2 I want to get dummy one and dummy two.

Comment: Hi @FreindlyAsianDev, did you get a chance to look into my answer? was it helpful?

Comment: yes i did Also Thanks For some Reason the Add comment Didn't Work

Comment: i have a question @PrasadTelkikar when i try to show it on a label or a combo box or anything that i can show the text it shows (Collection) or in a Textbox i do to tostring() but it doesnt work

Comment: it just shows System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]?

Comment: oh sorry never mind i fixed it thank you for all your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are exiting from `foreach` loop after the first iteration. Instead of returning from foreach loop, store each string into an `List<string>` and finally return entire list.

```
 var d = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
 var t = d.Where(g => g.Contains(cotainstring));
 //Defin result to store all satisfied strings.
 List<string> result = new List<string>();
 foreach (var item in t)
 {
     var splited = item.Split(new string[] { cotainstring}, StringSplitOptions.None);
     //Store the string in List, instead of return
     result.Add(splited[1]);
 }
 //Return entire string.
 return result;
```

If above code is written inside function, you need to update the return type of that function from `string` to `List<string>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *Linq* `Select` and some kinf of *materialization*, say `.ToArray()` to get a *collection* of dummies:

```
var lines = File
  .ReadLines(filPath)
  .Where(line => line.Contains(containstring)) // original query
  .Select(line => line.Split(                  // Select added
     new string[] { containstring }, 
     StringSplitOptions.None)) 
  .Select(items => items[1])
  .ToArray();
```